# Bible on Acrobat PDF with a static/top/center navigation bar with drop down menus for Book, chapter/verse

Tags: pdf, bookmarks, adobe-acrobat

I need to create a regular static navigation bar in all pages of my PDF Bible, so people can easily go to book/chapter/verse number.

Here is an example of what it should look like: http://www.biblehub.com/

I'm at the point where I have all the bookmarks I want, already showing in the Acrobat navigation pane. Now I need to arrange everything into 2 or 3 drop down list menus.

I realize I can then duplicate to show this navigation on all pages, I just learned how to do that with the buttons, so this feature would be great.

Since it's the Bible, there are 66 books and 1200 chapters so I can't do them manually nor make a button for each. There should be a way to populate the menus with their respective targets. I've seen some JavaScript snippets but don't have enough knowledge to figure out how to assign a target to each bookmark specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a quickly stated rough idea, but what would be possible is using a popup instead of a dropdown. The app.popUpMenuEx() method allows to create hierarchical popup menus, which would pretty much represent the structure you have in the bible. A popup is normally attached to a simple button field, where the mouseDown action creates and displays the popup, and the mouseUp action handles the selection.

Now, for the targets, it depends on how fine your granularity should be (meaning whether the page is sufficient, or whether you want to set a focus or zoom to the actual verse. It also depends a lot on whether and how a book/chapter/verse is identified in your document, and whether it can be located automatically on a page. If this is possible (meaning that we can clearly identify a verse/chapter/book by searching for "words"), we create a development script which reads out the information from the document, and then we can put that information into a table, which can be used by the popup.

This approach does require some knowledge of and experience with PDF and Acrobat JavaScript, and it may be worthwhile considering whether developing it by yourself would be worth the hassle, compared with hiring an expert who has done similar projects in the past (end of shameless plug).